# How can I achieve this in Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

am having problem achieving this result with array, I want to update another empty array with data in first array in such a way that the first two rows is ommitted and the first 3rows is added to the index 0 of the empty array, and the next 3 rows is also updated to the second index and so on.  I have this Array in

```
`$arr = [
    'tqty' => 9,
    'tPrice' => 18700,
    'food_name_1' => 'Black Coffee',
    'food_quanty_1' => 1,
    'food_price_1' => 1000,
    'food_name_2' => 'Sub Combo',
    'food_quanty_2' => 2,
    'food_price_2' => 3000
];`
```

I want to use this array data and update another empty array this way, removing the first two rows

```
$arr2 = [
    0 => [
         'food_name_1' => 'Black Coffee',
         'food_quanty_1' => 1,
        'food_price_1' => 1000
    ],
   1 => [
         'food_name_2' => 'Sub Combo',
         'food_quanty_2' => 2,
        'food_price_2' => 3000

    ]

];
```

here is my code so far

```
$arr = [
    'tqty' => 9,
    'tPrice' => 18700,
    'food_name_1' => 'Black Coffee',
    'food_quanty_1' => 1,
    'food_price_1' => 1000,
    'food_name_2' => 'Sub Combo',
    'food_quanty_2' => 2,
    'food_price_2' => 3000
];

$newdat = [];
$count = 0;
$oldcount = 1;
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    if(preg_match_all('!\d+!', $key, $matches)){

        if($oldcount == $matches[0][0]){
            $newdat[$matches[0][0]] = [
                $count => [
                    $key => $value
                ]
                ];
        } else{
            $count = 0;
            $oldcount = $matches[0][0];
        }
    }
    $count++;
 }
```

I hope I get help soon. thanks

Comment: Can the source array have further keys like `food_name_3` and respective data and so on...?

Comment: @9KSoft, Yes, The data is sent data html form that is generated automatically according the number a user entered

Comment: You might consider renaming your form inputs like `name="food[1]name"` etc. so you'll get a more usable array to begin with and avoid this manipulation.

Comment: good point @Don'tPanic knowing the source of the data could have made for a better question/answer.

Comment: There are many options in this thread now, but use a solution that allows your code to be tolerant of changes to your data structure. I wrote mine based on the pattern I saw in the key structure for the data grouping, and nothing positional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly,

```
$newdata = array();
for ($i = 1; $i++;) { // Intentionally no condition set.
    if (array_key_exists('food_name_' . $i, $arr)) {
        $temparray = array();
        $temparray['food_name_' . $i] = $arr['food_name_' . $i];

        if (array_key_exists('food_quanty_' . $i, $arr)) {
            $temparray['food_quanty_' . $i] = $arr['food_quanty_' . $i];
        }
        if (array_key_exists('food_price_' . $i, $arr)) {
            $temparray['food_price_' . $i] = $arr['food_price_' . $i];
        }
        $newdata[] = $temparray;
    } else {
        break; // break out of the loop
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($newdata);
echo "</pre>";
die();
```

Comment: Note: I've Updated my code :) Surprisingly had missed the syntax for `array_key_exists`, Dang its 4:30 in the morning here :P I guess I should go to sleep now. :D

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the array keys and order stay consistent you could use `array_chunk`

```
<?php 

$inArray = [
    'tqty' => 9,
    'tPrice' => 18700,
    'food_name_1' => 'Black Coffee',
    'food_quanty_1' => 1,
    'food_price_1' => 1000,
    'food_name_2' => 'Sub Combo',
    'food_quanty_2' => 2,
    'food_price_2' => 3000,
];

$outArray = [];

// Remove first 2 values.
$inArray = array_slice( $inArray, 2 );

// 'Chunk' the rest of the values.
// true preserves keys.
$outArray = array_chunk( $inArray, 3, true );

echo '<pre>' . print_r( $outArray, true ) . '</pre>';

/**
    Output:

    <pre>Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [food_name_1] => Black Coffee
                [food_quanty_1] => 1
                [food_price_1] => 1000
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [food_name_2] => Sub Combo
                [food_quanty_2] => 2
                [food_price_2] => 3000
            )

    )
    </pre>
 */
```

Comment: Hmm, did you mean to use `array_splice`? (I don't think `array_slice` removes anything.)

Comment: Nope, I did mean to use `array_slice`. Technically you are correct it does not remove anything, it returns a new array.

Comment: I adore the simplicity, +1

Comment: Trusting too much on the source array, will only lead to bugs if keys are missing or rearranged/sorted, which btw happens more often than we estimate. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that will locate the `_x` at the end to check its a digit

This solution does not worry about how many non numbered fields you have, or how many fields there are per numbered "row", they are also indexed based on the `_x` number.

```
$arr = [
  'tqty' => 9,
  'tPrice' => 18700,
  'food_name_1' => 'Black Coffee',
  'food_quanty_1' => 1,
  'food_price_1' => 1000,
  'food_name_2' => 'Sub Combo',
  'food_quanty_2' => 2,
  'food_price_2' => 3000
];

$arr2 = array();

foreach( $arr as $key => $value )
{
  $explode = explode( '_', $key );
  if( ctype_digit( $index = end( $explode ) ) === true)
  {
    if( isset( $arr2[ $index ] ) === false )
    {
      $arr2[ $index ] = array();
    }
    $arr2[ $index ][ substr( $key, 0, strlen( $key ) - 1 - strlen( $index ) ) ] = $value;
  }
}

print_r( $arr2 );
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [food_name] => Black Coffee
            [food_quanty] => 1
            [food_price] => 1000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [food_name] => Sub Combo
            [food_quanty] => 2
            [food_price] => 3000
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through it and build the array index string via variables.

```
<?php
$arr = [
    'tqty' => 9,
    'tPrice' => 18700,
    'food_name_1' => 'Black Coffee',
    'food_quanty_1' => 1,
    'food_price_1' => 1000,
    'food_name_2' => 'Sub Combo',
    'food_quanty_2' => 2,
    'food_price_2' => 3000
];

foreach(array("food_name_","food_quanty_","food_price_") as $v){


// replace the set value of 2 here with a count() on the $arr
// and some basic math - IF you are always sure you'll have 3 fields
    for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){
        $newarr[$i][$v.($i+1)]=$arr[$v.($i+1)];
    }

}

print_r($newarr);


 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already know that you need always the same indexes from $arr, you can use the array_keys function in order to index the associative array.

Example:

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);
echo '<br><br>'.$arr[$keys[1]];
```

Here is a complete example:

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);    #stores the associative keys by index
$arr2 = array();

/* For each array $arr do the following */
$limit = 5; #substitute this with: count($arraylist)
for( $n_array=0; $n_array<limit; $n_array++ ){
    $cur_arr = array(); #substitute with your: $arraylist[ $n_array ]
    for( $a = 2; $a<count($arr); $a++ ){
        $cur_arr[ $keys[$a] ] = $arr[ $keys[$a] ];
    }  
    $arr2[ $n_array ] = $cur_arr;
}
```

Hope it will be helpful